# Define file association in Mac with Electron

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I am trying to create a simple electron app, that opens Google office files from Google Drive, reads the link file and creates a new window containing that google doc page.

I can make it work, if I edit info.plist after building with electron-builder to make the app accept the file extensions '.gdoc, .gsheets and .gslides'.

Is there a smarter way that doesn't involve manually editing info.plist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Electron-builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder) is supposed to be able to do that through specifying the [FileAssociation](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/wiki/Options#FileAssociation).  I've read of various issues with this but haven't needed it myself yet– if it works for you, please report back.

There is also the Windows only [electron-regedit](https://github.com/Tympanix/electron-regedit) node module:

> "File associations, file icons & open with... for electron apps
>
> This module allows you to register your app in the windows registry,
>   manipulate context menus & handle native open, edit, print, preview
>   actions ect."

However for Google drive you might be looking at registering a protocol and url scheme. There is support for that [electron-packager](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/blob/master/docs/api.md#protocol)

> **protocol**
>
> *Array of Strings*
>
> The URL protocol scheme(s) to associate the app with. For example,
>   specifying myapp would cause URLs such as myapp://path to be opened
>   with the app. Maps to the CFBundleURLSchemes metadata property. This
>   option requires a corresponding protocol-name option to be specified.
>
> **protocol-name**
>
> *Array of Strings*
>
> The descriptive name(s) of the URL protocol scheme(s) specified via
>   the protocol option. Maps to the CFBundleURLName metadata property.